# Joining with gSSURGO with field polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatial-join

I am using field boundary polygons to get soil type information from gSSURGO (especially percent sand and clay).

Here are my steps:

1. I used zonal statistical as table tool to find what unique ID (MUKEY) is assigned into each field bounday. I was thinking to join with soil data at the end.
2. Using Soil raster provided by gSSURGO, I first joined with Chorizon table (where information for percent sand and clay are located) since raster layer only include (value, count, MUKEY). Once I joined table to raster I found there are many (Null) values since original information for percent sand and clay have Null values
3. Finally, I joined between field bounday with field in raster based on MUKEY.
   However, I also found there are many (Null) values. In other words, many fields do not have values for percent sand and clay.

What I want to do is that I have 1062063 field boundaries (polygons) and get the values of percent sand and clay from gSSURGO without having missing values. If some values are missing in gSSURGO, I would like to get the closest value from neighbor.